# VBA - Create a thumbnail on Loadpicture() in a Userform

Tags: vba, image, excel, userform

I'm loading pictures in multiple `Image` controls on a `Userform` using `Loadpicture()`, to create some kink of previews. (The user can then click on the `Image` to open the full size picture).

Since the preview `Image` on the `Userform` are about 1cm tall, I would like to load a thumbnail (smaller file size versions) of the pictures to limit memory usage, while still keeping the full-sized (megapixels) source pictures on the hard drive.

Is there a way to resize the picture imported at the loading event ?

PS : I'm not trying to change the visible height/width of the picture since `PictureSizeMode` is set to `fmPictureSizeModeZoom`.

Comment: I don't think you can create a thumbnail using VBA alone.

Comment: @TimWilliams. That's not the answer I'm looking for :-(, but at least that the word ('thumbnail') I was looking for ! Thx

Answer (score 2):

There's a hack-y way around to do this - basically:

- create a temp `Worksheet`
- create a shape and load the picture to it and resize the picture
- create a temp `Chart` and paste the re-sized picture onto it
- export the `Chart` to a temp file
- delete the temp `Worksheet`
- load the temp file to the `UserForm`
- delete the temp file

It is a bit ghastly, but it works. You might want to consider using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` whilst the code is running, but it is useful to step through the code below to see how it works.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ' size of thumbnail
    Dim lngSide As Long
    lngSide = 50

    ' input jpg and temp file path
    Dim strInPath As String
    Dim strOutPath As String
    strInPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Capture.JPG"
    strOutPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\temp.JPG"

    ' add a temp worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    ' load picture to shape and RESIZE
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=strInPath, _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
        Left:=20, _
        Top:=20, _
        Width:=lngSide, _
        Height:=lngSide)

    ' create a chart
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = ws.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, _
        Width:=lngSide, _
        Height:=lngSide).Chart

    ' copy shape picture to chart and export to temp file
    shp.Copy
    cht.Paste
    cht.Export Filename:=strOutPath, FilterName:="jpg"

    ' remove temp sheet (including shape and chart) with no alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' load resized temp picture to image control
    With Me.Image1
        .Height = lngSide
        .Width = lngSide
        .Picture = LoadPicture(strOutPath)
    End With

    ' delete the temp file
    Kill strOutPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Keep in mind that "I would like to load a thumbnail ... to limit memory usage" and eventually save a few ms on execution. I doubt loading the full-sized image then exporting to disk then importing again, all while adding/deleting sheets and dealing with multiple shapes would be more efficient.

Comment: @Tibo - if OP's collection of images is fixed then they only need to do this once.  If not then your point is well-made of course.

Comment: You're right. I totally forgot to mention that pictures are indeed downloaded (and saved on disk, only once in a while) then loaded dynamically (on user imput) and expected to change very frequently.